# Unable to See the Internal/Alpha app listing on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

**Problem Statement**

I have setup my already published app for an internal test track according to the [instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) provided by Google. However, I do get redirected to the page as shown in the image below. When I click on `download it on Google Play`, I am always redirected to the public version of my app instead of the internal testing version.

[image]

**Background**

I have introduced a functionality in the app that redirects the user to update the app. Prior to releasing to production, I would like to test this functionality with a group of internal testers.

**What I've already tried**

1. I have setup the testing users correctly by creating a list of such users.
2. I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847330/how-internal-tester-can-download-the-android-pre-released-app-build) question and have completed all the steps of publishing and shared the opt-in URL with my testers.
3. I have also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150130/play-store-alpha-test-download-link-not-working) question and have waited for multiple hours, as well as cleared `Play Services/Browser` cache on the devices that have the invited testing account set as the primary account

**What I really want**

What I would like to happen is to gain access to the Play Store listing page of the internal testing app and redirect to it from another build so that it can be ensured that after the update, the app works as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The listing for your internal version of your app is exactly the same as the listing for your public version. The user gets a small notification "you are a Beta user", but that's the only difference.

What do you expect different in the Internal listing?

Comment: I actually expected a different channel where my alpha/beta/internal test builds could be visible. If the store listing page is common across all channels (alpha/beta/production), I don't know how it could work, for an email address that has opted in for both alpha and beta testing that are running simultaneously.
Thanks for getting back though. It took around 72 hours for my build to be reflected on the store.

Comment: If an account is opted in to both alpha and beta (or any two channels) it will receive whichever app has the highest version code. This is because on android you cannot have two different copies of an app with the same package name on any device. And the help center says "If a user opts in to your app's internal test, they're no longer eligible to receive the open or closed test. To regain access to the open or closed test, the user must opt out of the internal test and back in to the open or closed test." https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Answer (score 0):

My internal test version became visible on Play Store after 72 hours, which seems to be far too long for an app that has been in the market since the last 1.5 years. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54530157/5047773) provided by [Nick Fortescue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635471/nick-fortescue) is correct in essence since I was expecting a different channel where I could access the internal test build.

Comment: Internal test versions should not take that long, you are right (but alpha and betas can). It is important to distinguish the two. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213 Internal tests are almost instantly published. But Open / Closed tracks are different - as they can go to anyone who opts in. It's worth reading https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213 to understand the difference